# Ubuntu 12.04.2 showing a kernel panic at the startup

Tags: 12.04, ati, kernel, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm using a Acer Laptop 5100 (Athlon 64 TK-53, ATI 1100, 320GB HD, 4GB RAM, Broadcom 4311 Wifi), and I was using for some time Ubuntu 10.04 and later 10.10 64-bit versions without a single freeze. I spent the last 4 days working on a way to make 12.04 LTS work on this machine. Thank god I bought a new HD and saved my original 10.10, because there's no way to make the new LTS run on this machine.

I downloaded and installed both 12.04.2 32- and 64-bit and none worked after the installation. As soon the machine starts, before the login screen, it shows a kernel panic in text mode, after that the machine freezes, and only the power button solves it. I tried Ubuntu 12.04.1 (32- and 64-bit), and they worked fine before the updates. Immediately after the updates, the kernel panic shows up on the login again.

I'm working on a 12.04.1 32-bit without the updates. Could it be related to the new HWE? Or does the new kernel have some issue with my hardware? Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you can, take a picture of the kernel panic error and update your answer.

Comment: I have an aspire 5100 series notebook as well. I should point out that this might be a hardware problem. There is a defect in the motherboard for this series of laptops. There is an ATI chip on the motherboard that tends to come loose if exposed to a little heat. I've seen videos of people removing this chip with a tealight candle. It's located apparently right below the left windows key so some people have actually managed to get around the problem by pressing down there rather hard. But this is just a possibility. May be a software issue as well.

Comment: For me, I get a fixed disc error no matter what when I boot. So what I did was install Ubuntu to an external usb harddrive and boot from there. It works great. But I don't know if you have the same problem or not.

Comment: Does the old kernel boot ?